# Comobox event SelectedValueChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

i have simple question may be someone asked it before me but i could not find it.Let say i have datatable that has some data from the database and i want to bind it to a combobox i use standart code like this

```
 comboBox1.BeginUpdate( );
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
 comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
 comboBox1.EndUpdate( );
```

The problem is during this binding the event `SelectedValueChanged` is fired.The problem is that rebind combo several times when outher values change and every time i must do sometihn like this

```
 comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler( this.comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged );
```

my question is there a smarter way to skip the event when i comes from databinding not from user input.The problem is that i want to do it some how globaly in my control that inherits combobox and not to do it everytime in every from
Best Regards,
 Iordand

Comment: you can think in another way : u can make a global variable set it to false and in this event check on it and after u complete all binds set it to true

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using the **SelectionChangeCommitted** event.

From MSDN documentation:

> **SelectionChangeCommitted** is raised only when the user changes the
>   combo box selection. *Do not use* **SelectedIndexChanged** or
>   **SelectedValueChanged** *to capture user changes*, because those events are
>   also raised when the selection changes programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I've always done as space cracker said. I create a global boolean variable named _isLoading and set it to true while loading my combobox, then back to false when it's done. Then in the event handler the first line is

```
if(_isLoading) return;
```